# Importing multiple tables needs automation

Tags: php, mysql

I am importing many tables from an old program into a php/mysql application - the files are large and need many changes to be normalized. I have programs set up to do everything but would like to get it to be more automated.

Trying to import some tables gets timeout errors before the process completes. There are currently 12 tables to be imported and converted. Many of them have around 12000 records or more. I have changed the program to only do 2000 records at a time, remember where it left off and let me import the next 2000. This is not however the best solution and I will have to do this conversion of the entire dataset perhaps 20 more times as the old data is still being updated. As it stands I will have to be chained to the computer for hours while it completes being ready to click the continue button when the process finishes.

Changing the timeout to a larger number has not been as helpful as I would like.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Hi Donald, welcome to StackOverflow! Much as it's nice to know who we're dealing with, please [don't use signatures or tag lines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). I take it you are importing data MySQL->MySQL? You don't mention the source database format... Also `Changing the timeout to a larger number has not been as helpful as I would like.` - why not? Are you aware that `set_time_limit(0);` allows infinite run-time?

Comment: The database format is an old language I used to use, I exported it to a tab deliminited file to import - set time limit - there is a time limit for php, one for mysql, and another for the sever software - iis in this case - I've seen programs in php that allow even hours to run - one is akeeba backup - it is interactive - i'd really like this to be as turn-key as akeeba is. Thanks!

Comment: since this is a (relatively) one-time operation, I would suggest writing a script that is designed to be run from the command line. Command line PHP scripts are not subject to a time limit and are also not at the mercy of needing an open browser session to continue running.

Comment: I have never come across a time limit for a MySQL connection as long as you keep executing queries regularly, although I don't claim to be an expert in MySQL as an application (I write a mean query, that's about as far as it goes) and I certainly am not an expert in IIS, so if you want a browser-based solution I shall bow out (gracefully?) at this point ;-)

Comment: I think that may be what akeeba does, it tests queries to see how long they take then does its work in smaller increments. command line php - i need to look into this - thanks for all your prompt advice Dave, much appreciated

Comment: well I'll be darned it does run on windows, more things to learn now - thanks again! :)

Comment: comand line php - will work - thanks so very much!

Comment: No worries :-D If/when you find a solution, please answer this question and accept your own answer (you have to wait a while before you are able to do this as a new user, a few hours I think). Alternatively, if there are no answers and you don't feel this would be of value to future visitors you can delete the question. I think I speak for everybody when I say we like to keep the site tidy - and we'd also appreciate it if you take 10 minutes to read the FAQ at some point, the community is very friendly and generous if you keep to the "rules" (although we're all friends here, aren't we?) :-D